# Local storage counter output

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, storage, local

I am busy making a phonegap app where I capture a number of variables and send them via email (for the sake of simplicity I have stipped it down to the bare essentials).

I am trying to store the subject of the emails in local storage for them to be sent via a separate click function at the end of the day and then erase them from local storage.

my code for sending the email looks like this (note that I am storing "var newFileName" in local storage):

```
function sendMail(imageURI, click){
                var newFileName =  'the fileName';

                localStorage.setItem('newFileName', newFileName);



                cordova.plugins.email.addAlias('gmail', 'com.google.android.gm');
                cordova.plugins.email.open({
                    app: 'gmail',
                    to: 'user@gmail.com',
                    subject: newFileName,
                    body: 'this is the body',
                    attachments: [imageURI],
                    isHtml:  true
                });

            };
```

now that I am storing the variables in local storage I want to send everything that has been saved using another function:

```
function endOfDay(data){
                var text = [];
                var ending = localStorage.getItem('newFileName');
                var salesman = $('#agent').val();
                var newsFileName = 'End of Day Report for Agent: ' + salesman;

                cordova.plugins.email.addAlias('gmail', 'com.google.android.gm');
                cordova.plugins.email.open({
                    app: 'gmail',
                    to: 'user@gmail.com',
                    subject: newsFileName,
                    body: 'end of day:' + ending,
                    isHtml:  true
                });
```

this works but it only displays the most recent sent emails subject. So it seems that local storage is over writing the subject each time I send a new email when what `I want to do is have all the subjects that have been sent throughout the day sent and then erased from local storage on success

Comment: use json to save an array instead of a single one. PS: it'shandier to use localStorage as a "namespace" rather than a method; var ending= JSON.parse(localStorage.newFileName); and localStorage.newFileName=JSON.stringify(newFileName);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it is working now. The solution was:

```
var newFileName = 'N' + result + '_' + agent + '_' + todayDate + '_' + newURI + '_' + depot + '_' + date;

localStorage.setItem('newFileName', localStorage.getItem('newFileName') + "," + newFileName );
```

Thanx to all for the help.

Answer (score 0):

While saving in locastorage do this

```
var newFileName =  'the fileName';
var temp=localstorage.getItem('newFileName');
var somearray=temp.split(',');
somearray_length=somearray.length;
somearray[somearray_length]=newFileName;
var somestring=somearray.join(',');
localStorage.setItem('newFileName',somestring);
```

at the end of the day

```
ending=localstorage.getItem('newFileName');
localStorage.setItem('newFileName',"");  //clear memory
```

I used comma(,) as separator, use any unique character that will not be in your subject lines.

Comment: Ah I see now that the error was because localStorage had a lower case "s". When I send the end of day report I see that it only displays the most recent subject twice rather than storing every subject line that has been send. So it sends "subject 3, subject 3" rather than "subject 1, subject 2, subject 3, etc...".

Comment: Thanx for your answer :) is there anyway to output all of the subjects that are stored in localStorage for 'newFileName'? as in "subject 1, subject 2, subject 3, etc..."?

Comment: This code should save all the subjects. If you print `ending` at the end it should include subject 1, subject 2, subject 3 and so on

Comment: I sent off a bunch of test mails to get a few subject lines and when I send off the end of day mail it only shows the latest subject twice "subject 3, subject 3". Could it maybe be that localStorage is getting the variable before the sendMail function has fired? Subject variable is grabbing values of other variables that are storing form information: